# Magento : One Page Checkout Alignment Issue (Payment Method)

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento, checkout

Im sure this is as obvious as the day and the night, but for the life of my I cannot see in the code why the PayPal and Purchase Order button and text do not line up on the same line.

Any help would be great

https://www.acuity-sports.com/onepagecheckout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, in your CSS, add `display: inline;` to the label for sp-methods -- something like this:

```
.sp-methods label {
    display: inline;
}
```

That will make the *display* of the label to be *inline* with the radio button.

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks!  Now I can call it a weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

```
<dl>
<dt>Coffee</dt>
<dd>Black hot drink</dd>
<dt>Milk</dt>
<dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

you see the html `HTML <dl> Tag` is automatically rendered in your browser on a different line
see example here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_dd_test

if you want to have it float you have to add css style that overwrites your `dt, dd` to  'float:left'

here is an example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Q7T9/